# On excluding ex-supervisor from project team in a funding proposal

Tags: funding, collaboration

I am preparing a project proposal on a topic in line with what I was working on at my previous university (University A). My ex-supervisor has recently submitted a proposal to another funding body. There are some overlaps between her project and the one I am preparing. I am considering not to include her or anyone in University A as collaborators because I don't see any added value with us both being in the same project team other than making the team looks bigger. We are otherwise on good terms. I am also thinking of including another academic who used to work at University A but has recently moved to another university. I believe he and my ex-supervisor are also on good terms. Would this be OK or would it be perceived negatively by the reviewers, who might know our work histories, or by my ex-supervisor? Or is it better for me not to apply altogether because of the overlaps? Or, would it be better to go ahead and include everybody in the team? I should add that my ex-supervisor knows of my intention to apply for this funding.

I would be grateful if someone could help me think through the advantages or disadvantages of each of these options, in relation to the possible outcomes of our applications.

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: I am pretty sure your reviewers will not care if you take your old advisor on or not (assuming that you indeed have and can demonstrate the competencies to do the project without her/hin, of course). Your advisor on the other hand my be annoyed, but in the life of every academic there comes a time when one needs to separate from the advisor - which is not always a pain-free process :)

Comment: @ff524, traditional engineering.

Comment: You should include X in your proposal if and only if X is organically part of the proposed project. Reviewers can tell when people/tasks/equipment are just glued on.